# Windows Phone sqlite select all

Tags: sqlite, select, windows-phone-8

I have a query which simply does, in a table named "CUSTOMER" a select all.

This is my Table:

```
public class CUSTOMER : Extension.Shared
{
    [PrimaryKey, Indexed]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    [Indexed]
    public string FULL_NAME { get; set; }
    public string PHONE_NO { get; set; }
    //public string PIVA_CF { get; set; }
    public DateTime? MODIFIED_ON { get; set; }
```

And this is the query which gives me the problem

```
public List<CUSTOMER> SelectAll()
    {
        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(DatabasePath());
        return conn.Query<CUSTOMER>("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER");
    }
```

Every times i run this operation, the query returns an error from SQLite.cs file:

```
if (r != SQLite3.Result.OK) 
{
    throw SQLiteException.New (r, String.Format ("Could not open database file: {0} ({1})", DatabasePath, r));
}
```

If the size can be a useful, this table has nearly 50000 records.
I have the same problem in a couple of tables with 100000 or 80000 records.
No problems with other Tables, no problem with other queries.

I can say this because since I thought the table was badly saved, I installed again and again the table, but I noticed that from the same page i can call this query without any problem, for all tables:

```
public List<CUSTOMER> SelectByFilter(string Filter)
{
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(DatabasePath());
    return conn.Query<CUSTOMER>(string.Format("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE FULL_NAME LIKE '{0}%'", Filter));
}
```

I don't really know where can this error came from. I don't know any size's restriction on Sqlite3. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This error tells that it cannot find the database at the path given check with isolated storage tool that the database exist in that place also check you are referencing the correct path to database file in your DatabasePAth() method or else try this

```
 public List<CUSTOMER> SelectByFilter(string Filter)
{


    string dbpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "yourdatabsefilename.db");
//database is in home directory not in any subfolders. then only this code will work

    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(dbpath);
    return conn.Query<CUSTOMER>(string.Format("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE FULL_NAME LIKE '{0}%'", Filter));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but my problem is the selectAll. i can perform without any problem selectAll of other entities from same databasePath, and also other operations from other queries in same entity